# Why does Postman error "unsupported media type" for a POST request in spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, postman

I have an entity class `State` which extends abstract class `Location` and implemented it's abstract methods. When I made a `PostMapping` request on postman with the content type set to Json, I got an error unsupported Media Type as shown below:

```
"error:" Unsupported Media Type,
"trace": org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTpeNotSupportedException:Content type:'application/json;...
```

Abstract class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Location {
@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "long")
private String longitude;

@Column(name = " lat")
private String latitude;

public Location (){}
//assessors & mutators ommited with abstract methods
}
```

Concrete State entity class:

```
@Table(name="State")
public class State extends Location {

@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]{5}")
private String sateCode;

@JsonManagedReference
@OneToOne(mappedBy="state",
cascade=CascadeType.All, fetch=FetchType.Lazy)
private City city = new City();
//constructors & other implementations omitted

@Override
public void setCity(String city){
this.city=city
}

public void setStateCode(String code){
this.stateCode = stateCode;
}
///getter omitted
}
```

Concrete City entity class:

```
@Table(name = "City");
public class City extends Location {

@JsonBackReference
@OneToOne(cascade={
CascadeType.DeTACH, CascadeType. MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name = "state_city_id")
private State state;

//constructors & other implementations omitted
@Override
public void setState(State state) {
this.state=state;
}
}
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "location/destination")
public class LocationController{ 
     @Autowired
    @Qualifier("stateImpl")
    private LocationService service;
    @PostMapping(value = "/state", consumes = org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void save( @Valid @RequestBody State s ,BindingResult theBindingResult,
            HttpServletResponse r) throws IOException{
    if(theBindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            throw new InputException("Wrong data input!");
        }
        service.save(s);
        r.sendRedirect("");
    }
@GetMapping()
public ResponseEntity<Object>findAll(){
return new ResponseEntity<Object>(service.findAll(),HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

Error message on postman:

```
"status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "trace": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8 not supported\r\n\tat...'
```

Comment: Annotate your method with `@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})`

Comment: Is there any dependency needed for this as I'm getting "Consumes cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: Ah sorry, try `@PostMapping(consumes = {"application/json"})`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the exception: "content type 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' not supported..."

Comment: Could you share the full controller correctly?`@RequestMapping(path="location/destination)` is above the class or LocationService ? Another thing is that when you perform POST/PUT for the request body, you should define `@RequestBody` in the method.

Comment: If error still exists, try to set media type by annotation like this-->
 `@PostMapping(value = "/path",consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`

Comment: @FaramarzAfzali the code has been edited with the complete controller class

Comment: The issue has seemed to be clear. The code was actually complaining of serialization like so : ```Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type State...```. But I don't understand how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

The code worked when I changed the `city` field in the `State` entity class like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="State")
public State extends Location {

@JsonBackReference
@OneToOne(mappedBy="state",
cascade=CascadeType.All, fetch=FetchType.Lazy)
private City city = new City();
}
```

And the `state` field in the `City` entity like so:

````
@Entity
@Table(name="City")
public class City extends Location {
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToOne(cascade={
CascadeType.DeTACH, CascadeType. MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name = "state_city_id")
private State state;
}
```.
Though I'm yet to understand what really happened behind the scenes.
````